# Adding letters and numbers to create a variable name

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

Let's say I have several variables, named `R1`, `R2` and `R3`.

I wanted to have a function `function[numberOfR_]` and I wanted to have the output of the function to be `R1` if the entered `numberOfR = 1`, `R2` if the entered `numberOfR = 2`, etc. I tried defining this function as follows

```
function[numberOfR_] = "R" + numberOfR_;
```

but it doesn't put the `R` and the number together as I hoped; instead, it just gives me

> ```
>  3+R' or '2+R'
> ```

not as a single variable name like `R3` or `R2`. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: `function[numberOfR_] := 
 Symbol /@ (("r" <> ToString@#) & /@ Range@numberOfR)` to give a list of a range, `function[numberOfR_] := Symbol@("r" <> ToString@numberOfR)` for one-shot  - and don't use uppercase initials for your symbols - asking for trouble...

Answer (score 2):

This is your function, but this kind of programming seems to be weird, try other ways to do want you want

```
f[numberOfR_] := Symbol["R" <> ToString[numberOfR]]
```

Comment: This is useful indeed!